# Chunked Transfer Encoding not working, response completely buffered by GFE

Tags: google-cloud-run

Cloud Run / the "Google Frontend" seems to completely buffer responses from a Cloud Run application, even when using chunked transfer encoding for the response. This is bad for incremental rendering.

I have a Java web app based on com.sun.net.HttpServer which supports chunked encoding for the response. Especially flushing the output stream creates a chunk, so I can do:

1. write response line
2. flush
3. compute for 10s
4. write more response lines

Locally, this results in a chunked response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 07 Mar 2020 17:08:10 GMT
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

1c
<first output>

14
<next output>

17
<next output>

0
```

Using curl, I can see the output appear incrementally.

In contrast, when deploying the same app in Cloud Run, the response gets fully buffered and returned in full, no matter how long the pause (many seconds), how many chunks or how much content is returned (I've tested up to several megabytes):

```
curl -v https://...
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< x-cloud-trace-context: 3872abb809e97a76298f4c46b9217656;o=1
< date: Sat, 07 Mar 2020 17:18:48 GMT
< server: Google Frontend
< content-length: 2450359
```

(Example has 50k chunks!)

Is there a way to have the GFE pass through the chunked encoding?

Comment: mernst, how did you solve the issue ?

Comment: Please see https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming that suggests this might be solved . I'm not sure I ever verified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Run does not support streaming responses where data is sent in incremental chunks to the client while a request is being processed. All data from your service is sent as a single HTTP response.

Also, the 'Content-Length' and 'Transfer-Encoding' headers are removed from responses your application may serve. Those headers are then added by the Google Front End and finally, the response is served.

**Source of information:**

1) Internal conversations with the Cloud Run engineering team.

2) Google Cloud Security Whitepaper that details the GFE (Google Frontend) which sits in front of Cloud Run Managed.

https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/security_whitepapers_march2018.pdf

Comment: Thanks for checking. Is that a conscious choice or ease of implementation? I would surmise that buffering in the GFE just adds cost!?

Comment: The GFE is a large global system of proxy load balancers that handle security, DoS, domain names, routing, etc. The GFEs support a wide range of Google services. I am certain that some choices were made for compatibility but also for the levels of support required when those services were designed. The GFE buffers your service response and then delivers once everything is collected. GFEs are not a pass-thru proxy.

Comment: I have yet to try it out, but it sounds like this has been addressed:  https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming

Comment: I use Cloud Run with firebase rewrites and a node docker container for the client and the server. I only receive a response when I ..close() the readable stream. I can make it work when I bypass the server endpoint using cors. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74590080/cloud-run-api-service-response-broken-when-i-use-firebase-rewrites