# cloud run api service response broken when I use firebase rewrites

Tags: firebase, mod-rewrite, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run, sveltekit

The firebase Sveltekit client app and server api use a google cloud run hosting container. This works fine when I use the cloud run url: `https://app...-4ysldefc4nq-uc.a.run.app/`

But when I use firebase rewriting the client works fine using: `https://vc-ticker.web.app/...` but receives 502 and 504 responses from the [API service](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server). The cloud run log does not show any errors, receives the client fetch POST request and returns a Readablestream response.
**But this API service response stream never arrives when using rewrites.**

firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",   !! NOT used, cloud run hosts the app
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "vc-ticker-app",
          "region": "us-central1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

+page.svelte client API request:

```js
const logging = true;
const controller = new AbortController();
let reader = null;
const signal = controller.signal;

async function streamer(params) {
  console.log("stream with logging:", logging, JSON.stringify(params));
  try {
    const response = await fetch("api/my-ticker", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(params),
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      signal: signal,
    });

    const stream = response.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream("utf-8"));
    reader = stream.getReader();

    while (true) {
      const { value, done } = await reader.read();

      if (done || response.status !== 200) {
        console.log("done response", response.status, done, value);
        await reader.cancel(`reader done or invalid response: ${response.status}`);
        reader = null;
        break;
      }

      // response ok: parse multi json chunks => array => set store
      const quotes = {};
      JSON.parse(`[${value.replaceAll("}{", "},{")}]`).forEach((each, idx) => {
        quotes[each.id] = [each.price, each.changePercent];
        console.log(`quote-${idx}:`, quotes[each.id]);
      });
      positions.set(quotes);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("streamer exception", err.name, err);
    if (reader) {
      await reader.cancel(`client exception: ${err.name}`);
      reader = null;
    }
  }
}

$: if ($portfolio?.coins) {
  const params = {
    logging,
    symbols: Object.values($portfolio.symbols),
  };
  streamer(params);
}

onDestroy(async () => {
  if (reader) await reader.cancel("client destroyed");
  controller.abort();
  console.log("finished");
});
```

I use the Sveltekit adapter-node to build the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From firebase support:

I got an answer from the engineering team. Unfortunately Firebase Hosting does not support streaming responses at the moment.  I’ve created a feature request so they will consider implementing it.

Please be informed that submitting a feature request doesn’t guarantee that it will be implemented. Keep an eye on the release notes.

I realize that this is not the answer you expected from me, but unfortunately there is nothing I can do about it.

Comment: I can confirm that streaming through Firebase Hosting while rewriting to Cloud Run still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

With [rewrite rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), you can direct requests that match specific patterns to a single destination.Check your  [firebase.json file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#the_firebasejson_file) and verify if the rewrite configuration in the hosting section has the redirect serviceId name same as that from the deployed container image,as per below example

```
   "hosting": {// ...
  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/helloworld",
    "run": {
      "serviceId": "helloworld",  // "service name" (from when you [deployed the container image][3])
      "region": "us-central1"     // optional (if omitted, default is us-central1)
    }
  } ]
}
```

It is important to note that Firebase Hosting is subject to a 60-second request timeout. If your app requires more than 60 seconds to run, you'll receive an HTTPS status code 504 (request timeout). To support dynamic content that requires longer compute time, consider using an [App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).
You should also check the Hosting configuration page for [more details about rewrite rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites). You can also learn about the [priority order of responses](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order) for various Hosting configurations.

Comment: 1) Because of the stream there is no timeout here. The Api service keeps on streaming. But when I abort the stream, the stream continues for 5 more minutes. Conclusion: the timeout is postphoned als long as the stream runs.
2) The rewite config looks OK. And te requests arrive. But API responses do not arrive.

Comment: You'r right about the timeout. Now it's working the request timeout closes the stream.

Comment: I am glad it helped, you may upvote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: The timeout is a kind of show stopper for this kind of project (a ticker). But I still try to find out whats wrong with my rewrites (without cors)? The ticker app is now a websocket webapp, without the need for hosting the API in the cloud. This works fine at no costs.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with an external link to the cloud run api service (cors).
But I still do not understand why It can't be done without cors using only firebase rewrites.

**+page.svelte client API request update:**
Now using GET and an auth token to verify the api request on the endpoint server

```js
const search = new URLSearchParams(params);
const apiHost = "https://fs-por....-app-4y...q-uc.a.run.app/api/yahoo-finance-streamer";
const response = await fetch(`${apiHost}?${search.toString()}`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "auth-token": await getIdToken(),
  },
  signal: signal,
});
```

**And a handle hook to verify the auth token and handle cors:**

```js
const logging = true;
const reqUnauthorized = { status: 403, statusText: 'Unauthorized!' };

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  let response;
  if (event.request.method !== "OPTIONS") {
    if (event.url.pathname.startsWith('/api')) {
      const authToken = event.request.headers.get("auth-token")
      const { error = null, decodedToken } = await decodeIdToken(logging, authToken)
      if (error) return new Response(error.message, reqUnauthorized);
      if (verifyUser(logging, decodedToken) === false) {
        return new Response(`user auth failed for: ${decodedToken.email}`, reqUnauthorized);
      }
    }
    response = await resolve(event);
  } else { // handle cors preflight OPTIONS
    response = new Response("", { status: 200 });
  }
  response.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*");
  response.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  return response;
}
```

Comment: This question addresses the same problem: "Chunked Transfer Encoding not working, response completely buffered by GFE" more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580674/chunked-transfer-encoding-not-working-response-completely-buffered-by-gfe